# Team speak SDK server

Tags: sdk, unity-game-engine, teamspeak

I want to integrate TeamSpeak into my Unity 5 project. I downloaded TeamSpeak SDK for Unity from their website and everything worked great. I created my own TS server, but when I put adress, port and password into unity plugin, it said, that It can't reach server. I have readed somewhere, that it has to be SDK server, to be able to connect with TS SDK. How can I create this SDK server? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK server is inside the Unity SDK itself. You can find it in Assets\TeamSpeak\Example\SDK_Binaries_Win32